# Jenkins Custom Workspace Is Empty

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'm looking at trying to set up Jenkins to move from TeamCity. I'm trying to configure my Jenkins project to use a Custom Workspace.

When I set the workspace I get an error on the form: "Custom workspace is empty".

I did Google for a solution but no success.

Does any one know what the error means? And how to solve it?

Comment: Is this actually an error that's stopping you from moving on, or is it just a notification? Jenkins might be warning you that there is nothing in that location in case you were expecting there to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I've seen in the past, this is a benign error indicating that the directory doesn't exist.  When the job first runs, the directory will be created - and the error will no longer appear.  If you don't want the error to appear at all, create the directory before you create the job.

Comment: Yep, that's just an error shown in the job configuration UI if the workspace directory doesn't currently exist.  It won't stop the job from running.

Comment: Jenkins folder contains empty 'temp' folder only